# How to find if string in dict as a part of a key with dots in string

Tags: ansible

Hello i am trying to find a string as a part of a key in a dictionary.(file list)
In the next step i have to loop over a list of strings and search for it in a dictionary.

Any help out there?

Thanks for advice

Example dict:

```
[
        {
            "atime": 1564643897.7426093,
            "ctime": 1564643891.0105128,
            "dev": 64768,
            "gid": 3007,
            "gr_name": "group",
            "inode": 2230336,
            "isblk": false,
            "ischr": false,
            "isdir": false,
            "isfifo": false,
            "isgid": false,
            "islnk": false,
            "isreg": true,
            "issock": false,
            "isuid": false,
            "mode": "0644",
            "mtime": 1564643891.0105128,
            "nlink": 1,
            "path": "/home/user/branches/user/roles/manage_users/vars/users/my.user.yml",
            "pw_name": "user",
            "rgrp": true,
            "roth": true,
            "rusr": true,
            "size": 776,
            "uid": 1050,
            "wgrp": false,
            "woth": false,
            "wusr": true,
            "xgrp": false,
            "xoth": false,
            "xusr": false
        }...
        }
    ]
}
```

The match should be in key path: in the dict.
Tried several things but the closest seems to be;

```
- name: compare lists 1
  debug:
    msg: "item" 
  when: "item in users_list.files"
  with_items: 
  - "{{ users }}"
```

But i cant get any result
Instead i get: Skipped

Expected Msg:

```
Msg: my.user
```

Comment: PLease post more details. what is value of users and users_list.files?

Comment: Hi users_list.files returns the dict in example above (basicly the outcome of module find (a list of files and thier attributes) .
users is for example a list of user names ex my.user i try to look for "my.user" in dict and if its found it should return : "my.user"

Comment: User my.user is not found in the list of files. List of files will have filename right

Comment: Yes i think its because it looks only for the whole value of the key path and maybe the search value has a dot in it

Comment: So you want to return `true` if the object has a `path` key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by myself:
The trick is to create a list of path objects first with json query.
After that u can use it  for comparing:

```
- name: create list of valid users
  local_action:
    module: find
    path: "{{ role_path }}/vars/users"
  register: users_list

- name: create list existing users
  win_shell: |
    try {
      # powershell supposed way
      $users=Get-LocalUser;echo $users.name
    } catch {
      #fall back 
      $users=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'" | select name;echo $users.name      
    }
  register: users

- set_fact: 
    found_users: []

- name: compare lists
  set_fact:
    found_users: "{{ found_users + [item[1]] }}"
  when: item[0].find(item[1]) != -1
  with_nested: 
    - "{{ users_list.files|json_query(query) }}"
    - "{{ users.stdout_lines}}"
  vars:
    query: "[*].path"

- debug: msg="{{ found_users }}"
```